# how to use mysql query inside the javascript, php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a JavaScript function onLoad a PHP page. Inside this JavaScript function, How can I use mysql query? Please Help me..

Comment: JS executes on the user's browsers and cannot access MySQL in any way except via a server-side proxy of some sort, e.g. a PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url:"ajax_page.php?branchcode="+branchcode,
            success:function(data){ 
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Failed to load.. Kindly try again!!");
            }
     });
});
```

I have solved by using this AJAX, jQuery code.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do that.  JavaScript code runs in the browser, which (presumably) doesn't have access to your database server, and it doesn't have facilities for talking to remote databases anyway.

What you'd typically do is perform the SQL query from your PHP code, running on the server, and put the results into the page that it sends to the browser.  If you want to use the results in JavaScript, you can make your PHP code generate a JSON string in a `<script>` tag so that the JavaScript code can just access a global variable that contains the data.

Or, you can use AJAX to load the data separately.  This involves another HTTP request to a PHP page on the server, which runs the SQL query and sends back the results.

Comment: What if he uses Server Side JS?

Comment: But he isn't, or he wouldn't have mentioned "onLoad" or PHP pages.